# How can i append <br> tags after a text element?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am parsing a HTML file with BeautifulSoup and got stuck with < br> tags.
I want to append < br> tag after inserting a list element, but it didn't work.
What is the easiest way to do this?

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(open("test.html"))
mylist = [Item_1,Item_2] 
for i in range(len(mylist)):   
    #insert Items to the 4. column
```

This is the default HTML:

```
<html>
 <body>
  <table>
   <tr>
    <th>
     1. Column
    </th>
    <th>
     2. Column
    </th>
    <th>
     3. Column
    </th>
    <th>
     4. Column
    </th>
    <th>
     5. Column
    </th>
    <th>
     6. Column
    </th>
    <th>
     7. Column
    </th>
    <th>
     8. Column
    </th>
   </tr>
   <tr class="a">
    <td class="h">
     Text in first column 
    </td>
    <td>
     <br/>
    </td>
    <td>
     <br/>
    </td>
    <td>
    <!--I want to insert items here-->
    </td>
    <td>
     1
    </td>
    <td>
     37
    </td>
    <td>
     38
    </td>
    <td>
     38
    </td>
   </tr>
  </table>
 </body>
</html>
```

This is the HTML i want to make

```
<html>
 <body>
  <table>
   <tr>
    <th>
     1. Column
    </th>
    <th>
     2. Column
    </th>
    <th>
     3. Column
    </th>
    <th>
     4. Column
    </th>
    <th>
     5. Column
    </th>
    <th>
     6. Column
    </th>
    <th>
     7. Column
    </th>
    <th>
     8. Column
    </th>
   </tr>
   <tr class="a">
    <td class="h">
     Text in first column 
    </td>
    <td>
     <br/>
    </td>
    <td>
     <br/>
    </td>
    <td>
    Item_1 <br>
    Item_2
    </td>
    <td>
     1
    </td>
    <td>
     37
    </td>
    <td>
     38
    </td>
    <td>
     38
    </td>
   </tr>
  </table>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can u post original html and html you want to get?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To append a tag, first create it with the `new_tag()` factory function, like so:

```
soup.td.append(soup.new_tag('br'))
```

Consider the following program. For every table cell (that is, every `td`) in the html, it appends a `<br/>` tag and some text to the cell.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html_doc = '''
<html>
 <body>
  <table>
   <tr>
    <td>
     data1
    </td>
    <td>
     data2
    </td>
   </tr>
  </table>
 </body>
</html>
'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc)
mylist = ['addendum 1', 'addendum 2']
for td,item in zip(soup.find_all('td'), mylist):
  td.append(soup.new_tag('br'))
  td.append(item)
print soup.prettify()
```

Result:

```
<html>
 <body>
  <table>
   <tr>
    <td>
     data1
     <br/>
     addendum 1
    </td>
    <td>
     data2
     <br/>
     addendum 2
    </td>
   </tr>
  </table>
 </body>
</html>
```